# Smallest unique subset - how is it called? How can it be computed?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Let's assume we have several sets: for example [c], [a, b, d], [b, e] and [a, d].

What is the smallest subset of each of these which is not a subset of any other set in the group?

Respectively, it is [c], [a, b], [e] and N/A.

Does this relation have a specific name? Is there a well-known algorithm to compute it?

Comment: Shouldn't the third one also be N/A?

Comment: @JohnGriffin, you're absolutely correct. Amended.

Comment: I suspect your notion of "smallest unique subset" is not well-defined.  I can envsion a collection of $3$-subsets of a universal set of seven points, in which any $2$-subset of any set is contained in only one of the $3$-subsets (I have in mind the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane)), while any $1$-subset is contained in other sets.

Comment: @hardmath Well, it's well-defined, it's just not unique. There can be arbitrarily many unique subsets of the same, smallest, size.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a [package](https://github.com/alussana/TrieSUS) that is intended to solve exactly this problem, efficiently.

> how is it called?

During my research I couldn't find a name for this algorithmic question, so I ended up calling it, just like you, "smallest unique subset".

> How can it be computed?

What I could find instead is a number of brute-force approaches to solve the problem. They are "compact" enough to be shown within this post, so I'm reporting one of them here, which I implemented in Python:

```
def find_sus(sets_dict: dict, set_key: str):
    s = sets_dict[set_key]
    other_sets_keys = list(sets_dict.keys())
    other_sets_keys.remove(set_key)
    for n in range(1, len(s) + 1):
        # Initialize a binary mask with the first n elements set to 1
        mask = (1 << n) - 1
        while mask < (1 << len(s)):
            subset = []
            # Iterate through the elements of the set and check if the corresponding
            # bit in the mask is set (1), if yes, add the element to the subset
            for i in range(len(s)):
                if (mask >> i) & 1:
                    subset.append(s[i])
            # check whether subset is sus
            sets_with_such_elements_number = 0
            for other_set_key in other_sets_keys:
                other_set = sets_dict[other_set_key]
                if all(e in other_set for e in subset):
                    sets_with_such_elements_number += 1
            if sets_with_such_elements_number == 0:
                return subset
            # Generate the next binary number with n 1s
            # This algorithm is known as Gosper's Hack
            c = mask & -mask
            r = mask + c
            mask = (((r ^ mask) >> 2) // c) | r
    return [""]
```

To find the smallest unique subset (SUS) for a set, the solution above enumerates, using the [Gosper's Hack](https://read.seas.harvard.edu/%7Ekohler/class/cs207-s12/lec12.html), the non-empty subsets of that set from the smallest to the largest, until finding one that is a solution, *i.e.* that is not a subset of any other set in the collection. This approach has exponential time complexity of $O(2^n*m)$, where $n$ is the number of elements in each set (assuming all sets have equal size) and $m$ is the number of sets in the collection.

Using `find_sus()` on your example of four sets...

```
sets = {
    '1':['c'],
    '2':['a','b','d'],
    '3':['b','e'],
    '4':['a','d']
}

for set_key in sets_dict.keys():
    sus = find_sus(sets_dict, set_key)
    sus = "\t".join(sus)
    print(f"{set_key}\t{sus}")
```

... will give:

```
1   c
2   a   b
3   e
4
```

This approach works but, even after taking some relatively obvious precautions such as making sure that potential solutions containing the least frequent elements in the collection are tested first, it scales badly with input size (see [Performance](https://github.com/alussana/TrieSUS#performance)). It is even worse for sets for which a SUS doesn't exist - since all the possible non-empty subsets will be evaluated before finding that no solution exists.

So in case you want to look even further, my algorithm uses a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure and a series of linear time operations to first greatly reduce the problem size, and to then transform it into the equivalent of a [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), the solution of which is extracted using [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization)'s constraint programming solver. More information about the algorithm and its performance can be found in the [repository](https://github.com/alussana/TrieSUS).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2042588)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @julio_es_sui_glace , I edited the answer accordingly.